# Twilio Caller Id and Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, twilio

I am working with asp.net identity in MVC. I am checking phone number addition. For this i am using twilio trial account. Here i have 2 confusions regarding twilio integration.

1. For sending verification code or message to the registered mobile, firstly i need to add the destination number to twilio caller id and verify the number. But i am confused, is this the general approach? How this is practical or i missed out anything ? (or only trial has this limitation)
2. How many caller id (destination numbers) can add in twilio trial account? Any limit? I din't found information about this

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

A trial account has the restriction that you can only call or send SMS messages to phone numbers that have been verified and added as Caller ID's.  An upgraded account does not have this restriction.

I do not beleive there is any limit to the number of Caller ID's that can be added to a Twilio trial account.

Hope that helps.